# Java : Convert Jackson (JSON) class to Entity (JPA) Class

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

> I have two classes that have same fields. However, one is for the JSON
>   and the another is for the JPA Entity. I want to convert the JSON
>   object (Student) into the JPA Entity (StudentEntity). I tried to parse
>   the JSON class into the JPA Class, however it didn't allow. How can convert the (Student) Json class into (StudentEntity) class so that information I have in the JSON class can be used to persist in the database from JPA Entity Class?

```
package com.student.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class StudentEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private long studentID;

    private String fName;
    private String lName;

    private Address address;

    public long getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(long studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.ejb.objectmapper.entity.student;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("studentID")
public class Student {
    private long studentID;
    @JsonProperty
    private String fName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String lName;

    private Address address;

    public long getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(long studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a converter method and use getters and setters to create a new Entity using values from the JSON class?
Obviously you can't just cast Student to StudentEntity because they are not related in any way.

Comment: Converter method is a simple and elegant solution, everyone reading your code would know what it's for. I guess you could use reflection to set fields given that they are of the same types but the idea of doing this for such a simple task sounds pretty ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use the [Mixin feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) for Jackson.

This, essentially, would allow you to get rid of the `Student` class (if possible), and unmarshal the JSON directly to a new instance of the `StudentEntity` class.

This approach depends heavily on how complex your web application is, and how reliant you are on sticking with the [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) pattern. [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) does this quite successfully. In fact, since you are already using JPA, I would recommend it (if it suits your use case), and, as with many things Spring, you get a lot of stuff for 'free'.

Comment: To elaborate, this is a similar approach to the one suggested by @raminr, except you can have separation of concerns by keeping your Jackson annotations in an isolated class (or interface!)

Answer (score 1):

You could use some Mapping-Framework for that, i.e. Dozer (http://dozer.sourceforge.net) or MapStruct (http://mapstruct.org)

Using Dozer copying the classes boils down to something as simple as

```
dozer.map(jsonObject,Entity.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have been using the Dozzer Mapper. but I am trying to do it without using any APIs.

Comment: Hmm without any APIs you have to code it by hand ... doing essentially the same as Dozer or Mapstruct ;)

Comment: haha ... :)  MapStruct is new to me, I will try this one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for MVC? If you use Spring MVC, you can just use the JPA entity to represent the JSON payload. Works well for us. And just use Jackson annotations to control the behavior, like `@JsonIgnore`.

You don't need two classes.